# Is there any idea about “remove duplicate request using Postman after recording script”

Tags: python-3.x, http, postman, http-post, postman-collection-runner

when I use the postman to recorder requests, I alsways get a large number of repeated requests, How can I take som action to remove duplicate request using Postman after recording script

Answer (score 0):

1. step1: export scripts from postman
2. step2: using python script to remove the duplicated requests, and save file
3. step3: import the new json file to postman using another collection and remove the older